# How to type a class as one of its sub-classes dynamically

Tags: java, class, generics

I may have the wrong idea with this but bear with me...

I have a function that I want to call with one of multiple sub-class types ComboA, ComboB, etc (all extending the superclass "Combos").

```
    ArrayList<Combos> combos = null; //of type combos, which is super class of Combo A and Combo B
    switch (which) {
        case 1:
            combos = CombosA; //this is of type ComboA
            break;
        case 2:
            combos = CombosB; //this is of type ComboB
            break;
}
```

Depending on the switch statement, I want a single variable in the function (combos) to retain all the class functions of the sub-class.  This is so I don't have to make a bunch of functions for each Combo type -I'd like to use the same variable name (combos) regardless of which subclass it is.

I tried using generics, but the thing is, the CombosA and CombosB variables are defined outside of this scope, global to the class, and I don't know how to use generics unless I define the function as

```
public <E extends Combos> void Test(ArrayList <E> CombosA)
```

Or something like this, which I guess would require another separate variable to be sent in the function call that wasn't global.  I might be able to copy the CombosA array list and send the copy into the function to get the generic function to work but, I thought there must be a better way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This has nothing to do with generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you next want to do with the selected "`combo`".  Since `ComboA` and `ComboB` are subclasses of `Combos` ideally you would just call a "Combos" method to perform a common action on each combo.  Each subclass can then perform it's own implementation of the function.

For example, if you are going to do some sort of update on `ComboA` or `ComboB` etc, then there could be an `update()` method (possibly abstract) in the `Combos` class.  `ComboA` has its version of `update()` and `ComboB` has its version of `update()`.  Your loop then just loops over the combos calling the `update()` method knowing that each will do the correct thing without having to specify type.

Does that help?

Comment: But ComboA and ComboB both have different variables that are necessary for the rest of the function to run.  Like, ComboA might have a variable A that ComboB does not have - and ComboB has B but ComboA doesn't, but instead of writing two totally different functions with a bunch of repeated code, I wanted to create a single function with a few switch statements, just switching the important lines like changing ComboA.getA() to ComboB.getB().  Is my design wrong, or does that make sense?

Comment: Hello Anthony.  What you want to do is right (ComboA and ComboB can and should have different variables, methods etc), but when you want to deal with them in a common way (as your loop is doing), that loops needs to call a common method (and not care about whether it's A or B etc).  That common method can make use of common code in the common parent class, just passing the specific different up to the parent method as parameters.  Alternatively, you can put this common code in some closely related helper class that both ComboA and ComboB use.

Comment: It's been a while but I came back and looked at this answer to realize you are right.  I needed to add a common method that handled the difference within the object itself instead of trying to pull that logic out where it doesn't belong.